# How to make editable objects in the designers `Collection Editor Windows`?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2015, custom-controls

I created a custom component, derived from TDataSet.
Now I created a collection from a custom type `dsTable` named `gttTables`. (all the code is below)

When I drop the component on a form, the collection `gttTables` shows up in the `property window` and when I click on the 3dotted button, the `Collection Editor Windows` appears as expected.
In the `Collection Editor Windows` I can click on `Add` and that will add a new item in the window which seems to be of the type `dsTable` as I expected.

Now for the problem.
In the `Collection Editor Windows` I cannot see/change any of the properties of each `dsTable` in the list on the left. The right side only shows `Value` the value is `gttControls.dsTable`.
Let me show you what I mean with this picture

[image]

I would like to see the properties of each `dsTable` added to the `Collection Editor Windows` here instead, so I can edit them.

Here is my complete code.
My question is what should I do so I can edit the properties of each added `dsTable` in the `Collection Editor Windows` ?

```
public partial class gttDataSet : DataSet
{
    Collection<dsTable> _dsTables = new Collection<dsTable>();

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor, System.Design", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [Category("GTT")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public Collection<dsTable> gttTables
    {
        get { return _dsTables; }
        set { _dsTables = value; }
    }
}

public class dsTable
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string SelectText { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string SelectTextForUpdate { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string DesignWhereText { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string UserWhereText { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    bool IsStoredProcedure { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    bool RetrieveColumns { get;  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I looked at [How do you create a custom collection editor form for use with the property grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530074/how-do-you-create-a-custom-collection-editor-form-for-use-with-the-property-grid) and though it contains usefull information it seemed not necessary in my case. The answer of @Serg fixed my problem

Comment: Take a look at [How to Edit and Persist Collections with CollectionEditor (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio) and [Creating a Custom Collection for Use in a PropertyGrid (CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24332/Creating-a-Custom-Collection-for-Use-in-a-Property) and [Design-Time Support for Custom Controls](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.742.1/design_time_support_for_custom_controls.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a custom collection editor form for use with the property grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530074/how-do-you-create-a-custom-collection-editor-form-for-use-with-the-property-grid)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thanks for the link, I will study it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your `dsTable` class properties `public` to be able to edit these properties with `PropertyGrid`

```
public class dsTable
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string SelectText { get; set; } // <--- changed here

    //make the same changes for other properties you want to edit.
}
```

Comment: Omg so simple, how could I not see this. Thank you so much