# C#: Property `Get` method not being called by PropertyGrid when updated

Tags: c#, .net

I've been stuck on this problem for a bit, and I can't seem to wrap my head around where I am going wrong with this. I have a class `UnitInfo` with several properties which are used to populate a `PropertyGrid` in a winform. The properties:

```
public class UnitInfo {
    public byte[] data { get; set; } = new byte[5];
    public int serialNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)data[0] & 0b0111_1111;
        }
        set
        {
            data[0] = (byte)(((int)data[0] & 0b1000_0000) | (int)value);
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

The rest of the properties are similar. When I update any property but `data` in the `PropertyGrid` the changes to `data` are immediately shown. For example, if I change the serial number by manually typing a value into the `PropertyGrid` then `data` will update accordingly. However, the reverse isn't true. If I modify `data` in the `PropertyGrid` to change the value of the `serialNumber` then `data` will update but `serialNumber` will not.

I may be wrong in my understanding of `PropertyGrid` from reading through the docs, but shouldn't the `Get` method of all properties be called when one is changed? That's what seems to be happening when any property modifies `data`.

Why won't properties update when `data` is modified?

Comment: This question is phenomenally unclear. Please edit your question to change the names of the class and the byte array property to different names so we can figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield sorry about that, I modified the names to make it (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: You are never updating `data`. The `set` method of data is never called. You are only changing the state of that byte array, the property never changes, it always stays the same 5 bytes (the just have different values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decorate the properties with the `RefreshPropertiesAttribute` to notify the PropertyGrid that it should handle updating the object.

```
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
public byte[] data { get; set; } = new byte[5];
```

Do this for each property on the class that you want to be responsive to editing in the PropertyGrid control. Note that for this property in particular, you have to assign a *new* byte array, not just modify the values of the existing array.

Comment: This works great! However, it requires that I click on properties in the `PropertyGrid` for them to be refreshed. Is there a way to tell the PropertyGrid to refresh all properties when `data` is modified? I've put the `RefreshProperties` attributes on all of my properties in the class

Comment: Try `RefreshProperties.Repaint` instead of `.All`

Comment: I tried using `Repaint` but still the same behavior. It definitely works well enough though. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with yourPropertyGrid.Refresh()? See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the PropertyGrid does not update completely if you programmatically change dependent properties. In one of my projects I call PropertyGrid.Refresh() after programmatic changes for this reason. However I cannot prove this by citing MSDN.

So if you know in the setter of data that serialNumber depends on data (which PropertyGrid certainly does not now of), then call PropertyGrid.Refresh() in data.set (which requires you to write out the setter explicitely).

Maybe there is also a different way with events however.

**Edit:** see also this question (and answer): [PropertyGrid doesn't notice properties changed in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092162/propertygrid-doesnt-notice-properties-changed-in-code)