# How can I update propertygrid item values when another item changed in winform c#?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a property grid with 2 items. Country & Cities. I have 1 table in database : CountryCityTable that save LocationId, Title , ParentId. For countries parentId = 0 and for cities is countryid.

In my propertygrid, I use these and show in 2 combobox items. Please see my code :

```
namespace ProGrid
{
    public class KeywordProperties
    {
        [TypeConverter(typeof(CountryLocationConvertor))]
        public string CountryNames { get; set; }

        [TypeConverter(typeof(CityLocationConvertor))]
        public string CityNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace ProGrid
{
    public class CountryLocationConvertor : StringConverter 
    {
        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {            
            HumanRoles Db = new HumanRoles();
            List<LocationsFieldSet> Items = new List<LocationsFieldSet>();
            Items = Db.LoadLocations(0,0);
            string[] LocationItems = new string[Items.Count];
            int count = 0;
            foreach (LocationsFieldSet Item in Items)
            {
                LocationItems[count] = Item.Title;
                count++;
            }
            return new StandardValuesCollection(LocationItems);
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;//false : If you want the user to be able to type in a value that is not in the drop-down list.
        }
    }

    public class CityLocationConvertor : StringConverter
    {
        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            HumanRoles Db = new HumanRoles();
            List<LocationsFieldSet> Items = new List<LocationsFieldSet>();
            Items = Db.LoadLocations(1,20);
            string[] LocationItems = new string[Items.Count];
            int count = 0;
            foreach (LocationsFieldSet Item in Items)
            {
                LocationItems[count] = Item.Title;
                count++;
            }
            return new StandardValuesCollection(LocationItems);
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
KeywordProperties Kp = new KeywordProperties();
myPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = Kp;
```

Now, I want when user changed country title in propertygrid, List of cities updated(just display cities that parentid of these = countryid).

Also, in my class how can i change Number 20 in my code(**Db.LoadLocations(1,20);**) to selected country id ?

Thank's.

Comment: Apply the [RefreshProperties] attribute.

Comment: Please change my code with this attribute. Thank's.

Comment: Like Hans said, this property works nicely and is very clean. Also check for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955653/586754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement something similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged`

[Microsoft INotifyPropertyChange Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

In other word, you will need to have some event raised when you chance one property. As far as I remember, the property grid automaticly check for that type of event/interface and refresh the correct property node when the event is raised.

The important part is:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and

```
public bool MyBoolProperty
{
    get { return  myBoolField; }
    set
    {
        myBoolField = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

If you want to do something that is not covered by the PropertyGrid, you simply need to register your own method in the `PropertyChanged` event and do whatever you please.